# Springboot JPA Hibernate - Fetch auto-incremented value other than primary key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a model where the primary key (String) is generated with a UUID generator. This is working fine when I insert value to db.

Because of an external dependency, I have to add another field (of type big int) to this entity which also should auto-increment. I have configured it to increment at the db level. But even though this newly added field is getting properly inserted (auto-increment works fine) in db, its value is not getting reflected back to the model I am using to save. Even if I read the model explicitly using the PK, value of this second field is missing. Can some one help please ?

Stack : Spring boot 1.5.2,Hibernate 5.0.12 and MariaDB 10.1.22

This is my model: Other fields omitted for brevity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    private static final String ID = "id";
    private static final String MAPPING_ID = "mapping_id";

    @Id
    @Column(name = ID, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private String id;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = MAPPING_ID, nullable = true)
    private Long mappingId; //newly added field. 

}
```

**Update 1:**

Tried without @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO), still bad luck.

Comment: Please show us your code ;)

Comment: `@GeneratedValue` is only applicable for `@Id` fields, it will not work on other fields. If you want to obtain the value from the database first clear the enttymanager and reload the item from db. If you don't clear the entity manager before retrieval you will get the value from the first level cache.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, I am relatively new to to this stack. Don't know much about clearing entity manager. Have to read about it.